# Flutter keeps throwing an error, while defining CognitoSignUpOptions

Tags: flutter, authentication, aws-amplify

```
 Error: The argument type 'Map<String, String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<CognitoUserAttributeKey, String>'.
```

When I looked up the error there was no information about it.

On the AWS documentation they recommend this code, which leads to the error:

```
Map<String, String> userAttributes = {
   'email': 'email@domain.com',
   'phone_number': '+15559101234',
   // additional attributes as needed
};

SignUpResult res = await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
   username: 'myusername',
   password: 'mysupersecurepassword',
   options: CognitoSignUpOptions(
     userAttributes: userAttributes
   )
 );
```

Answer (score 9):

The solution is quiet simple.

You have to change the constructor of the Map:

```
Map<CognitoUserAttributeKey, String> userAttributes = {
CognitoUserAttributeKey.email: 'email@email.com',
CognitoUserAttributeKey.phoneNumber: '+15559101234',
};

void registerAccount() async {
  await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
    username: 'myusername',
    password: 'mysupersecurepassword',
    options: CognitoSignUpOptions(
     userAttributes: userAttributes)
  );
}
```

This solves the problem.